# Check if user have shared the page on social networking website?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any generic solution available to check if user have shared the page on social networking sites like facebook, google+ and twitter.

My exact scenario is that I want to see if user have shared my content on social networking site or not.

Comment: why do you want to know if the user shared it? what for exactly?

Comment: @luschn In my app, i will give points to users if they share the page on social networking sites. Hence I want to track if they have shared it or not.

Comment: ok, then i know the answer

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments, you want to reward users for sharing something, which is not allowed. People always have to like or share something ONLY because they want to, not because they get something out of it.

> 4.5 Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

That being said, you can check out the callback function of the share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog